How can I query ListView records based on some criteria using Force API
I have created a ListView on Accounts where Industry is 'Technology' in Salesforce.
We have a partner system which pulls Accounts from the above ListView using Force API.
In the partner system we have to do incremental sync of the Accounts.
Use Case:

We have 20 Accounts in the ListView on 10/07/2024.
We sync above 20 Accounts to Partner System on 10/07/2024 from the above ListView.
On 11/07/2024 We have added 5 more Accounts to the above List.
When we do sync again to Partner System on 11/07/2024, we have to pull only the newly added 5 Accounts which are added to the ListView after the first sync.

As of now we are using below API which returns all the 25 records
        ExecuteListViewRequest listViewRequest = new ExecuteListViewRequest()
        listViewRequest.sobjectType = 'Account'
        listViewRequest.developerNameOrId = '0015g000XXXXXXXX'
        listViewRequest.limit = 50000
        ExecuteListViewResult result = partnerConnection.executeListView(listViewRequest)

Is there a way to fetch records from the ListView based on the record added time ?

Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] if you haven't already, and take our quick [tour]. What you're trying to do isn't possible through this call. Please read about the X-Y Problem, then [edit] your question to include what you're trying to do. This will help us give you an appropriate solution.
